# Populating list of lists with doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode throwing exception 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, html-agility-pack

I have the following code working with a C# WPF form that keeps throwing an exception when I try accessing labels[2][0].

```
List<List<string>> labels = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='prod-att-table']")
                            .Descendants("tr")                                
                            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("th").Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

The html page I am working with is this digikey page: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/yageo/RC0402JR-0710KL/311-10KJRTR-ND/726418

Looking at the page source code I realize that the third "tr" descendant in table "id='prod-att-table" doesn't actually have a "th" element like the rest do. The problem I am having is that I cannot figure out how to get labels[2][0] to not throw an exception. Is there a way in my code that I could go about skipping this null element to not add it to my list? or maybe replace these nulls with empty string ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid null entries you can use following code:

```
var list =  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='prod-att-table']")
                .Descendants("tr")
                .Where(x=>x.Elements("th") != null && x.Elements("th").Count() != 0) //new Code
                .Select(tr => tr.Elements("th").Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

A better way to get the items (at least on the link you provided) would be this:

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='prod-att-table']");
var nodes = table.SelectNodes(table.XPath + "//th").Select(x => x.InnerText.Trim()).ToList();
```

But be aware this will give you a `List<string>` instead of `List<List<string>>`. Don´t know if this is intended.